# Emoji into textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, chat, emoji

I tried to insert Emojis into a textarea, but it didn't work. The emojis did not display.

```
<span class="text">',params.text.replace(/:(\w+):/g,'<img src="emo/emojis/smile.png" alt="smile"/>'),'</span>
```

What could be causing this?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

A simple textarea cannot show images as is intended to hold plain text only, use a `div` instead. I've posted a JSFiddle link below to give you an example.

If you must allow user input in the `div` then set the `contenteditable` property to `true`.

```
<div id="someDiv" onclick="showImage();" contenteditable="true">Click Me!</div>

<script>
function showImage()
{
    return document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = "<img src='http://ladiesloot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/smiley-face-1-4-15.png' height='250' width='250' />";   
}
</script>
```

The link below shows you a `div` with the `contenteditable` property set to `true` that means the user can type.

If you click the `div` it should put an image in the `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/05dLkuc0/

Comment: I already changed to a div and not load the image but load the image size.